# Negative form or "No"?

Tags: differences, negation, no-not

I have some confusion about these two forms below:

***- I am no Politician***

***- I am not a Politician***

Same goes with:

***- I have no friends***

***- I don't have friends***

Comment: _I am no [occupation]_ has the idiomatic meaning "I am certainly not a [person of that occupation] and have no expert knowledge in the field" - for example "I'm no doctor, but I can see that you ought to be at home in bed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Not"* negates the meaning of the modified verb when used as an adverb.
>
> *"No"* means "not any" when used as a determiner.
>
> A good way to remember the difference is that *"not"* works with verbs and *"no"* works with nouns.
>
> *"Not"* is usually used to modify verbs. It negates the meaning of a verb. If a verb did not occur, you will use *"not"*. Sometimes not accompanies nouns, but it only works with nouns that have an article (a, an, the). It can also come before an adverb, such as *"not many"*.

[Source](https://prowritingaid.com/grammar/1000173/No-vs-not%E2%80%94what-is-the-difference)

But they basically have the same meaning in your sentences, just different usages.

Comment: You need to put anything you're directly quoting in blockquotes.

Comment: @Laurel sorry my bad, I'll keep that in mind for future posts!

Comment: "Not" negating a noun, as in "not a sound could be heard".